# explode by the last match character inside any block

Tags: php, explode

As everyone knows explode works for any character that match the results.

I want to make the same effect but for the last element that match the internal block.

for example

```
$explodeMe = ' [ [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ] ] , [ [ [ 5 , 6, 7, 8 ] ] ]';

$explodeMe = explode( ']' , $explodeMe);
```

// this will explode $explodeMe 6 times (for each ] character)

I want to explode it for each block (in that example 2 times) `[[[]]] [[[]]]`

so :

if the block is open by 1 `[ (.*) ]` it will explode it with the first ]

if the block is open by 2 `[[ (.*) ]]` it will explode it with the second ]

if the block is open by 3 `[[[ (.*) ]]]` it will explode it with the third ]

maybe a function that count the [[[ character and by this value look for the last

```
]]]
  ^
```

this is the syntax without the function :

```
$explodeMe = explode( myFuntionToLookForTheLastElementForEachBlock(']') , $explodeMe);
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: OR MAYBE FIND ANY ] ELEMENT THAT DO NOT HAVE ] BEFORE

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Why don't you just explode your string on `] ,` or `] , [` at the place of complicating your head with getting the count of `[` etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to parse this sting of structured data and build a multi-level array from it. You've given us an example of some data you want to "explode", and in this case it kind-of resembles JSON.

If you're sure that this is how all the data you'll have to handle will look, the possibly easiest way to read this data is to `json_decode('['.$explodeMe.']', true)` and process the resulting array further from there.